# Tax From Changed for Nexus

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to create sales orders using WebServices from our CRM (Salesforce) to NetSuite. I am having an issue with international sales orders, in particular I am hitting this issue with United Kingdom.

If I create a sales order in the UI and set a bunch of field values and then set the Address to United Kingdom, I get a popup with the following message:

> The address you have selected is based in a nexus for which you are required to charge a different kind of tax. Click OK to change the form to one that is applicable for that Nexus.

In the UI, when you click "ok", the page reloads and a few new tax fields appear (the fields are built in, denoted by the field ids). The problem is when the page reloads, all of the data is wiped out.

I did this UI testing to determine what was causing this. However, in WebServices, all the data sets at once (not able to be done in any "order"). What is happening with my webservice call is that it gets this same warning and then all of the data it tried to send is lost and then it tries to submit the record, hitting validation rules we have in place.

Has anyone hit this before? Is there a field or something I can set via webservices that is what NS is doing on the backend when you click "ok"?

I am open to any solution. I do have a ticket open with NS Support, however so far they have not been helpful. If I do get a resolution, I intend to post it for others.

Comment: FYI - NS has so far logged this as a defect. Has anyone ever hit this before? How did you get around it? I can't wait for them to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

to get around it, you can access the vendor first then select dropdown icon to open the purchase order

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).